# Поиск таблиц, к которым идет обращение из хранимых процедур при помощи c#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

Добрый день!
Стоит задача найти все таблицы, к которым идет обращение в хранимых процедурах SQL.
Есть код SQL:

```
INSERT INTO @Id SELECT id FROM таблица WHERE //и далее
```

`@Id` определен в другой таблице.

Под это дело написаны методы:

```
internal class SQLVisitor : TSqlFragmentVisitor
{
    private HashSet<string> tables = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

    public override void ExplicitVisit(InsertStatement node)
    {                
        var tableName = node.InsertSpecification.Target as NamedTableReference;
        if (tableName != null)
        {
            tables.Add(tableName.SchemaObject.BaseIdentifier.Value);
        }
    }

    public override void ExplicitVisit(SelectStatement node)
    {
        var querySpecification = (node.QueryExpression as QuerySpecification);
        var tableName = querySpecification?.FromClause?.TableReferences[0] as NamedTableReference;
        if (tableName != null)
        {
            tables.Add(tableName.SchemaObject.BaseIdentifier.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

В данном случае `tables` - список таблиц, к которым идет обращение из хранимых процедур.

Проблема заключается в том, что при поиске через, к примеру, `InsertStatement`, получается найти только INSERT, а все, что дальше, SELECT FROM в том числе, считается кодом для INSERT-a. При поиске через `ExplicitVisit(SelectStatement node)` этот блок считается блоком INSERT-a и таблица пропускается. Каким образом можно вытянуть SELECT из этого блока?

Answer (score 0):

Есть системное представление sys.all_sql_modules, которое дает определения SQL-объектов. Если читать именно исходную задачу - то берете список таблиц. Для каждой таблицы ищете вхождения в поле [definition] этого системного представления.

```
declare @search_string nvarchar(100) = 'dbo.Persons'

select
  [object_id]     = o.[object_id],
  [object_name]   = quotename(s.[name]) + N'.' + quotename(o.[name]),
  [object_type]   = o.[type],
  [definition]    = m.[definition],
  [charindex]     = ci.[charindex],
  [line]          = null,
  [level]         = 0,
  [line_start]    = null,
  [line_end]      = null,
  [create_date]   = o.[create_date],
  [modify_date]   = o.[modify_date]
from sys.all_sql_modules    as m
inner join sys.all_objects  as o on o.[object_id] = m.[object_id]
inner join sys.schemas      as s on s.[schema_id] = o.[schema_id]
cross apply
(
  select 
    [charindex] = charindex(@search_string, m.[definition])
) ci
where ci.[charindex] > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Кажется, вы забыли вызвать базовый метод, вот обход дерева и "обрубается".

Описание используемого вами класса я не нашел - но, по всей видимости, вам надо добавить что-то вроде вот такой строчки: `base.ExplicitVisit(node);` в оба ваших метода.